# how to resolve urlopen error in robotframework?

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

**Code**
    Below sample code for calculator android program testing used robotframework AppiumLibrary

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary     run_on_failure=Log Source
#Library           Selenium2Library
#Library           OperatingSystem

#Setup    Open    Calculator
#Teardown    Close    Application

*** Variables ***
${DEV.APPIUM_SERVER}    =   https://127.0.0.1/wd/hub
${DEV.PLATFORM_VERSION}     =   7.0.1
${DEV.PLATFORM_NAME}    =   Android
${DEV.DEVICE_NAME}  =   device1 
${DEV.PACKAGE_NAME} =   com.google.android.calculator
${DEV.ACTIVITY_NAME}    =   com.android.calculator2.Calculator

#Elements locators for various
${EQUALS_SIGN}  =   xpath=//*[contains(@text,'=')]
${DISPLAYED_RESULT} =   xpath=//*[contains(@resource-id,'id/result')]


${td_Digit1}    =   5
${td_Digit2}    =   2
${td_Expcted_Addition_Result}   =   7
${td_Expected_Subtraction_Result}   =   3

*** Keywords ***    
Open Calculator App
    Open Application    ${DEV.APPIUM_SERVER}    platformName=${DEV.PLATFORM_NAME}   platformVersion=${DEV.PLATFORM_VERSION}     deviceName=${DEV.DEVICE_NAME}   appPackage=${DEV.PACKAGE_NAME}      appActivity=${DEV.ACTIVITY_NAME}


Enter Digits And Operator
    [Arguments]     ${digit1}   ${digit2}   ${operator}
    Click Element    xpath=//*[contains(@test,'${digit1}')]
    Click Element    xpath=//*[contains(@text,'${operator}')]
    Click Element    xpath=//*[contains(@text,'${digit2}')]

View Result

    Click Elemet    ${EQUALS_SIGN}
Verify Result
    [Arguments]  ${expected_result}
    ${displayed_result} = Get Element Attribute  ${DISPLAYED_RESULT}  text
    Should Be Equal  ${displayed_result}  ${expcted_result}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1: Addition
    Open Calculator App
    Enter Digits And Operator   ${td_Digit1}    ${td_Digit2}    +
    View Result
    Verify Result
```

**Above code after running below error seen**

Test Case 1: Addition
**URLError:urlopen error unknown url type: = http**

Appium server is already running in the system. Kindly help me find the error

Answer (score 0):

Missing the port on the AppiumServer URL, from examples:

`http://localhost:4723/wd/hub`

In your case (if really is HTTPS to localhost), maybe you could try:

`http://127.0.0.1:443/wd/hub`

Comment: Thanks for your comments.it is not working. Same error exist